# CAS: "allowedAttributes" is invalid in CAS 4.2.1

Tags: cas

Since I have problems with the `serviceRegisty.conf`, I tried the `serviceRegistryDao`:

```
<bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
        <property name="registeredServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
                    <property name="id" value="0" />
                    <property name="name" value="HTTPS" />
                    <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTPS Urls" />
                    <property name="serviceId" value="https://**" />
                    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
                    <property name="allowedAttributes">
                        <list>
                            <value>cn</value>
                            <value>description</value>
                            <value>telephoneNumber</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

If I don't use "allowedAttributes" everything works fine, but I don't get the attributes I want (I get non). So guessed that I need to add which attribute the clients should recieve. However, I get the following exception:

```
2016-09-21 16:17:40,674 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTicketRegistry': Inject
ion of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManager org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry.logoutManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logoutManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jasig.cas.services.ServicesManager org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutMana
gerImpl.servicesManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servicesManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Tomcat%20Servers/Tomcat%20CAS%20Server/webapps/cas/WEB-INF/lib/cas-server-core-services-4.2.0.jar!/org/jasig/cas
/services/DefaultServicesManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.jasig.cas.services.ServiceRegistryDao]: : Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: C
annot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl#286fad61' of type [org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl] while setting bean property 'registeredServices' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl#286fad61' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'allowedAttributes' of bean class [org.jas
ig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl]: Bean property 'allowedAttributes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'serviceRegistryDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl#286fad61' of type [org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl] while setting bean property 'registeredServices' with key [0]; n
ested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl#286fad61' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springfram
ework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'allowedAttributes' of bean class [org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl]: Bean property 'allowedAttributes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My suspicion is that this way of dealing with services is no longer supported by CAS 4.2.x, but I am not sure.

**EDIT:**

I also tried this:

```
<bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
        <property name="registeredServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
                      p:id="5" p:name="https.all" p:description="Allow HTTPS connection"
                      p:serviceId="^https://.*" p:evaluationOrder="5"  >

                    <property name="attributeReleasePolicy">
                        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I thought by that I might get all attributes. I can run the tomcat server now and also log in etc. But I still dont get the attributes.

Comment: What dependencies do I need else at the CAS client and server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The configuration is invalid because that's not how 4.2 works. Consult the docs to learn the new syntax. You also need to make sure your application is hitting the right endpoint.